# is there any if statement for showing/hiding a method in objC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

i use same uiviewcontroller's instance in different tabs.
there is a uitableview in viewcontroller.
in firstviewController instance, i dont wanna edit the uitableview.
in the second one i use edit mode for tableview.
thats why i want to show or hide this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

is it possible to make an if statement like this:

```
#if (editingOK)
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
....some codes
}
#endif
```

editing OK is a BOOL property.

if you ask why i want it, because if the user swipes on the cell, it display Delete button.
i just want it if my editingOK=YES.

Comment: I think your syntax my be causing confusion. The #if - #endif construction is a compile time syntax, and so not useful for dynamic programming. C and friends use "if (test) { do_this_if_true(); } else {do_this_is_false();}" sort of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#if/#endif` syntax is used for conditional compilation: it lets you modify your program at *compile time* based on build configuration. Read about the "C preprocessor" to learn more.

If you are, as you say, using the same object *instance* as the delegate of different UITableViews, you must have some way to determine which table you are dealing with.

What you need to do is implement an additional method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That method is called when the user swipes the cell, and you can decide if a delete button should appear or not, then return the appropriate `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` constant.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't editability controlled by calling the setEditing method of the UITableViewController? So you could set that depending on whether or not you want to enable editing, w/o this #ifdef ugliness.